# Why does React Native webview fails to load images when opened second time?

Tags: ios, react-native, safari, uiwebview, react-native-ios

I am rendering remote images inside a webview in react native ios.

The image tag looks like this
`<img src="https://example.in/1222asdasdas.png" alt="bug-tracking-tips-01">`

The webview loads the images from the remote url and everything works fine the first time I load the webview.

But the next time I open the webview the image does not appear and when I inspect in safari, this error is shown `An error occured trying to load the resource`.

An interesting thing however is that if I have multiple instances of webview, each webview loads images for the first time and fails in the successive trials.

How can this be solved?